# Force check constraints to be evaluated before computed columns

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns, check-constraints

I want to have a JSON column in a table. I want to have (persisted) computed column that extracts useful information from the JSON data.
I want to have a "strict" JSON path but I also want to check that the path exists in the JSON so that the error message is specific to the table and isn't just about the illegal JSON path.

```sql
CREATE TABLE DataWithJSON (
  DataID BIGINT,
  DataJSON NVARCHAR(MAX) CONSTRAINT CK_DataWithJSON_DataJSON CHECK (
    ISJSON(DataJSON) = 1
    AND JSON_VALUE(DataJSON, 'lax $.Data.ID') IS NOT NULL
  ),
  DataJSONID AS JSON_VALUE(DataJSON, 'strict $.Data.ID') PERSISTED
);

INSERT INTO DataWithJSON (DataID, DataJSON)
  VALUES (666, N'{"Data":{"Name":"Tydýt"}}');
```

This code returns (on my machine) somewhat mysterious error message

> Msg 13608, Level 16, State 2, Line xx Property cannot be found on the specified JSON path.

I would like to see more specific message

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line yy The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_DataWithJSON_DataJSON". The conflict occurred in database "DB", table "schema.DataWithJSON", column 'DataJSON'.

Is this possible to achieve just with table constraints or am I out of luck and do I have to check the JSON in a stored procedure/application before inserting to the table?

*One* solution would be to have "lax" path in the computed column, which, hopefully, is not the *only* solution. I will fall back to that solution if there is none other to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the order that check constraints and computed columns are evaluated but you can use a `CASE` expression in the computed column definition so that the `JSON_VALUE(... 'strict ...)` part is only evaluated if the check constraint would pass.

```
CREATE TABLE DataWithJSON (
  DataID BIGINT,
  DataJSON NVARCHAR(MAX) CONSTRAINT CK_DataWithJSON_DataJSON CHECK (
    ISJSON(DataJSON) = 1 AND JSON_VALUE(DataJSON, 'lax $.Data.ID') IS NOT NULL
  ),
  DataJSONID AS CASE WHEN ISJSON(DataJSON) = 1 AND JSON_VALUE(DataJSON, 'lax $.Data.ID')  IS NOT NULL THEN JSON_VALUE(DataJSON, 'strict $.Data.ID') END PERSISTED
);
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 9 The INSERT statement conflicted
> with the CHECK constraint "CK_DataWithJSON_DataJSON". The conflict
> occurred in database "Foo", table
> "dbo.DataWithJSON", column 'DataJSON'. The statement has been
> terminated.

Comment: What an `AHA!` solution. But it seems too complicated. I will probably drop the `strict` requirement in our production code. `lax` check constraint with `lax` computed column will be sufficient and more concise. I guess I was suffering from the "hey, that seems nice, I want to use it" syndrome.